# not-found page of NextJS is automatically refreshing the website

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, app-route

My NextJS App is refreshing again and again by itself when I am hitting a route that is not defined.

Here is my folder structure.

```
App
 - Home
    page.js
 - Service
    page.js
 page.js
 not-found.js
```

The **not-found.js** is below:

```
const NotFoundPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Sorry this page doesn't exist</p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default NotFoundPage;
```

**version:**

```
"next": "13.4.5",
"react": "18.2.0",
```